# Introduction dates of different 74xx or 40xx chips?

Tags: cmos, ttl, history

The 74xx family debuted in 1964 with the 7400 chip, and the 4000 family debuted in 1968, but not all chips with 74xx or 40xx part numbers debuted anywhere near that time.  If one wanted to invent a hardware design that was period-correct for e.g. 1976, how would one find out which 74xx, 40xx, etc. parts would have been available at that time?  Some chips would seem to be in just about every way superior to others, suggesting that people probably used the generally-inferior chips because they were available first, but perhaps there were other reasons such as fabrication cost, speed, or power consumption.

Is there any easy way to determine which parts that are reasonably available today (if not still manufactured) would be suitable for period-correct designs?

Comment: Find a 1976 electronics magazine and look at the adverts

Comment: Or find the 1976 edition of the databook for the part family you want to use.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7400_series mentions years for many series releases (not just under history).

Comment: I'd probably take a shortcut and use only what's found in the 2nd edition of Texas Instruments' (1976) TTL Data Book for Design Engineers (which I still have a copy of here): http://maben.homeip.net/static/S100/databook/1976%20TI%20DataBook.pdf

Comment: @Tut: The page gives releases for the series, but I'm more interested in the individual chips.  Would a 16x4 FIFO like the CD40105BE, 4x4 register file like the 74xx670, or a dual 64-bit shift register like the CD4517BE be things an engineer or hobbyist could have used in the mid 1970s?

Comment: @supercat ... Good point. I used to have those books, but the earliest logic databooks I am finding now are a few from Motorola and from National dated 1983.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, there is no official list of introduction dates for 74xx and 40xx devices.  It is possible however to show that a device was available by a particular year, by virtue of it being listed in the catalogues in that year (and later years if not discontinued).

This [is the May/June 1966 TI price list](http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/ti/priceLists/TI_Semiconductor_Price_List_May66.pdf) (PDF) which lists their semiconductor products at the time of printing, and shows what 74xx series devices were available at that time:

[image: 66 price list of 74 series devices]

Quite the range, and only $85 (2017) dollars for a 7474 D flip-flop!

[Bitsavers also has copies](http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/ti/_dataBooks/) of the 1967-68 TI IC catalogue, the 1971 TI IC catalogue and the 1976 TTL Databook (a catalogue and datasheets for their parts).

Using these, you can set an approximate window on the release of a part -- a part which is listed in the 1976 catalogue but not 1971 catalogue can be assumed to have been introduced after of the printing of the '71 catalogue.

Some things to keep in mind.  Especially in the 1960s, things that were listed by manufacturers were not necessarily actually available on the market at the time of introduction (unless you were the US government building an ICBM), due to limited production volume.  Similarly, parts may have been available for direct order after being "discontinued" and delisted in the catalogues, particularly with the Databook which was intended as a reference for new designs.

Comment: "only $85 (2017) dollars for a 7474 D flip-flop" ... not that you'd actually have been able to buy one, because AIUI the entire production capacity at that time was booked up by US government purchases (either DOD or NASA, basically).

Answer (score 0):

It will be easy to identify *fake* device because it should not only claim to be of specific year, but also contain chips and other parts of that datecode or earlier.

For retro-computing remakes (versus original devices) functionality is important, not much component base and their date of make.

Comment: My interest is not in building a machine with antique physical parts, but rather in producing designs which would have been practical in the periods of interest (for some projects, early 1970s; for some late 1970s; for some early 1980s).

Comment: Ok, you did not disclose the purpose. In any case do not claim that designs which you create to be of that time. There will be people who will find discrepancies and errors, and losing the face with it is not a good idea :) If you make it for educational or historical purposes, why not just to search some IP from that time, and have *genuine* material with author names?

Comment: Sorry the phrase "period-correct design" wasn't clear.  If someone wants to design a board that could plug into a 1970s COSMAC VIP and play four-voice music, the easiest way to do that would be to make a board containing a cheap ARM that has 5V-tolerand inputs and a built-in DAC.  That wouldn't seem very satisfying, though, since an ARM could just as easily replace everything else.  A design which uses common off-the-shelf parts from that era but is simpler and cheaper than using a pair of COSMAC Super Sound cards would seem much more interesting.

Comment: Agreed. Retro computing may be a kind of "religious" matter, working in this domain always keep in mind that some people can be mortally offended by your stance :) thus just keep genuine and do not claim more than needed. Good luck.

Comment: I think this is an interesting thing to do; designing with parts of that era. I wonder if the manufacturers may be able to furnish the required information. They will surely know, and probably have somebody in customer services who would find this an interesting query to assist with.

Comment: This is brave expectation, I think it is reasonable to expect that they are interested in revenue and profits, and as this request is not related to any of them, they may turn it down referring to web sources or datasheets.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question the [1976 TI TTL databook](http://maben.homeip.net/static/S100/databook/1976%20TI%20DataBook.pdf) and examples of early-mid 70's Period layouts.  I wish I had some of the 50+ Layer boards designed and built at the plant we closed down, the gold plating tank was as big as transport truck.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I think the best example of 1976 Analog Design was from Tektronix.
[image]
[image]

For digital design I would say HP was by far the best in 1976 with Silicon on Sapphire CPU's and gold plated tracks, not just card edges with 30 of  80 Alphanumeric characters on micro-LED display. This was introduced in 1976 and I was the first user to use DMA control in a SCADA control system communicating between two computers over 1 mile apart on the HP9825's with real-time data every second on 200 channels.

That year Wozniak was working on his Apple ][ which was released in 1977.

I had one project around that time using two of these HP-Basic calculators and I turned them into a complete SCADA system with remote control over 96 Analog and digital controls and used the keycodes for toggle commands menu-driven with confirmation feedback and a CRT master monitor for remote Black Brandt umbilical control. All State attributes were stored in Non-Volatile high speed cartridge tape on the left side by simply pressing the [Save] button..
[image]

Here's a [bunch](http://www.rsp-italy.it/Electronics/Databooks/ICs/) more 1976 databooks

Comment: Do you know whether the 74595 and 74597 came out in relation to the 74164 and 74165 or other shift-register chips?

Comment: correction I got that wrong LS595 came out just before in '72 while LS164/165  circa'74.. but at that time 74xx was being replaced with 74S and 74LS then later but LS  74L . Not every OEM introduced at the same time ,but figure a new databook every week we had to keep up pretty fast.

Comment: by 1976, nobody was using 74xx family except legacy old stuff and mainly using 74LS or CD4xxx CMOS unless speed was a premium then 74S or ECL. Boards then could be replaced by a single chip today. So a backplane with 40 PCA's on 44 pin connectors with wire-wrap was my choice then with coax for critical analog on the backplane. ( that was using Mil-std wiring in Aerospace)

Comment: Date codes aren't useful here. They identify when a specific unit was manufactured, not when the part was first introduced (possibly by a completely different manufacturer).

Comment: I thought he wanted to find parts from that era too. A little research can derive the exact NPI dates for each family is possible. but why? -1 is so lame

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 The question makes it pretty clear that they're looking for period parts that are still "reasonably available today" (i.e, in production, or readily available as NOS). Either way, though, your answer doesn't really -- well, answer the question. It's an interesting discussion of your personal history, but it doesn't all add up to an answer.

Comment: @duskwuff all he has locate the Databooks from that period, here's more;  NSC,Harris, RCA, TI, Fairchild, BB, Motorola or lookup the datasheet for the original copyright date for every part.  It's easy but tedius

Comment: I had all the databooks from every source at the time. It was a huge library. But if he is making something that must be period accurate only parts with those date codes will do, like boards from a PDP11 or boards built from that period. Any pro can spot  the current date codes and see it as a fake.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear that the OP wants to create something *using the parts available at the time*, not a "forgery". Like somebody today making mediaeval armour isn't trying to fool people that it's actually hundreds of years old, just making it period authentic.

Comment: there is no substitute for authentic date codes on parts. Don't forget to use only Kemet solid Tantalum Caps, Alum E-caps were not good enough at that time.

Comment: The discussions of designs don't particularly answer my question, but the databook links seem helpful. Actually what might be even more interesting would be scans of period catalogs from Jameco or other suppliers. The fact that a particular vendor charges $10 for a some chip while many chips are $0.19 wouldn't necessarily indicate that the chip was rare or exotic, and the fact that a chip sells for $0.09 wouldn't imply that it was commonplace (it could be that nobody ever bought any and the distributor simply wanted to get rid of them) but the catalog would still tend to indicate availability.

Comment: The problem as I see it is your goal is unspecified with your question. Realism and authentic period parts and then designs of 1976 I have defined . unless you can be more specific in full details of your goals or questions, I cannot assist you. Yet I have all the answers on this, because I lived and breathed it. In other words the best solution  is limited only by the quality of the specifications. If you did not experience it, how can you judge?  Witness that your questions regarding 74xx family and 1976 is false assumption as 74xx series was dead and old news long before this